# Numbers of relatively primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inclusion-exclusion

Here's a problem I saw recently:

> How many of the integers $n$ with $1\leq n\leq 150$  are relatively prime to $70$?

Can someone help me with it? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Here's my approach to this problem:

*My attempt:*

> Notice that $70=2\times5\times7$. Hence if $n=p_1p_2p_3...p_n$ and $\gcd{(n, 70)}=1$, then $p_1,p_2,p_3,...,p_n$ must not be $2$, $5$, or $7$.

From here on I don't know what to do except for listing all the numbers out. :(

Comment: If you don't have any ideas, then you could just start writing down numbers. There are only 150 of them, and if you spend two minutes you'll see some *very* obvious patterns.

Comment: You could expand the question a little bit if you want to have it reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prime factors of $70$ are $2,5$ and $7$.

Use inclusion/exclusion principle in order to calculate the amount of numbers in the range $[1,150]$ that are not divisible by either one of these prime factors:

$$150-\left\lfloor\frac{150}{2}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{150}{5}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{150}{7}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{150}{2\cdot5}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{150}{2\cdot7}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{150}{5\cdot7}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{150}{2\cdot5\cdot7}\right\rfloor$$